# Display and register custom categories for custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Ok here we go. I have 2 different custom post types. The first is called 'portfolio', the second one 'games'.

All the game reviews I write are 'games' posts. To have a better overview I created custom categories like reviews, playstation xbox etc. Unfortunately everytime I would like to display the posts of one categorie (http://www.zock-around-the-clock.com/games_category/testcategory) I just get an 404 Error Page.

I dont really use the 'portfolio' posts but with them the arrengement into categories would work just perfectly. (http://www.zock-around-the-clock.com/portfolio-view/testcategory).

I would like to ask you what is the difference between these two types and why is it working with the portfolio posts but not with the games posts.

I also tried adding normal categories into the games posts by adding `'taxonomies' => array('category'),` but unfortunately it is still not possible to display the games posts of a single category.

Here's the single-portfolio.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $lightbox = $custom["lightbox-url"][0];
?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('post'); ?>>
  <article class="single-post">
    <header>
      <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </header>
    <div class="post-content wrapper">
   <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
                echo '<div class="featured-thumbnail no-hover"><div class="img-wrap">'; the_post_thumbnail(''); echo '</div></div>';
                }
            ?>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
      <?php wp_link_pages('before=<div class="pagination">&after=</div>'); ?>
    </div><!--.post-content-->
  </article>
</div><!-- #post-## -->

<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
```

and the init. for the portfolio posts:

```
function my_post_type_portfolio() {
register_post_type( 'portfolio',
            array( 
            'label' => __('Portfolio'), 
            'singular_label' => __('Porfolio Item', 'theme1575'),
            '_builtin' => false,
            'public' => true, 
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'page',
            'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/images/icon_portfolio.png',
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'portfolio-view',
                'with_front' => FALSE,
            ),
            'supports' => array(
                    'title',
                    'editor',
                    'thumbnail',
                    'excerpt',
                    'custom-fields',
                    'comments')
                ) 
            );
register_taxonomy('portfolio_category', 'portfolio', array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Portfolio Categories', 'singular_name' => 'Category', "rewrite" => true, "query_var" => true));}add_action('init', 'my_post_type_portfolio');
```

Here's the single-games.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?><div id="content" class="grid_8 <?php if (of_get_option('blog_sidebar_pos') == "right" ) {echo "alpha";} else {echo "omega";} ?> <?php echo of_get_option('blog_sidebar_pos') ?>">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('post'); ?>>
  <article class="single-post">
    <div class="post-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php $post_meta = of_get_option('post_meta'); ?>
        <?php if ($post_meta=='true' || $post_meta=='') { ?>
            <div class="post-meta">
                <?php _e('Geposted am', 'theme1575'); ?> <span class="date updated"><?php the_time('j. F, Y'); ?></span> <i><?php _e('by', 'theme1575'); ?> <span class="vcard author"> <span class="fn"><?php the_author_posts_link() ?></span> </span></i>
            </div><!--.post-meta-->
        <?php } ?>      
    </div>
    <div class="post-content wrapper">
    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
                echo '<div class="featured-thumbnail no-hover"><div class="img-wrap">'; the_post_thumbnail(''); echo '</div></div>';
                }
            ?>
      <?php the_content(); ?><?php wp_link_pages('before=<div class="pagination">&after=</div>'); ?>
    </div><!--.post-content-->
  </article>



        <?php /* If a user fills out their bio info, it's included here */ ?>
  <div id="post-author">
    <h3><?php _e('Written by', 'theme1575'); ?> <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></h3>
    <p class="gravatar"><?php if(function_exists('get_avatar')) { echo get_avatar( get_the_author_email(), '80' ); /* This avatar is the user's gravatar (http://gravatar.com) based on their administrative email address */  } ?></p>
    <div id="author-description">
      <?php the_author_meta('description') ?> 
      <div id="author-link">
        <p><?php _e('View all posts by:', 'theme1575'); ?> <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></p>
      </div><!--#author-link-->
    </div><!--#author-description -->
  </div><!--#post-author-->

</div><!-- #post-## -->


<nav class="oldernewer">
  <div class="older">
    <?php previous_post_link('%link', __('&laquo; Previous post', 'theme1575')) ?>
  </div><!--.older-->
  <div class="newer">
    <?php next_post_link('%link', __('Next Post &raquo;', 'theme1575')) ?>
  </div><!--.newer-->
</nav><!--.oldernewer-->
```

and the init. for the games posts:

```
function my_post_type_games() {
register_post_type( 'games',
            array( 
            'label' => __('Games'), 
            'taxonomies' => array('category'),
            'public' => true, 
            'query_var'=> true, 
            'publicly_queryable'=> true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'games-view',
                'with_front' => true,
                'hierarchical' => true,
            ),
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => array(
                    'title',
                    'author',
                    'thumbnail',
                    'revisions',
                    'comments',
                    'editor',
                    'excerpt')
                ) 
            ); register_taxonomy('games_category', 'games', array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Games Categories', 'singular_name' => 'Category', "rewrite" => true, "query_var" => true)); } add_action('init', 'my_post_type_games');?>
```

Comment: Did you reset the permalinks after creating custom-post-type. This is a common issue and often we ignore visiting permalink page. Just visit Settings>Permalinks page. Although you don't have to do anything there. Just visiting the page updates the custom-post-type settings. Please confirm..

Comment: No way...spent the last few days to fix this and a simple permalink update does the trick...amazing thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Put hierarchical=false (in the post type) if you have a wordpress > 3.6. I think there is a bug that prevents the taxonomies to work correct, I've used that trick to my cpt / custom taxonomy and it works ok.

Comment: Putting hierarchical=false changed nothing however, a simple permalink update does the trick. But now the metadata for the posts are enabled, is there a way to disable them?

Comment: From Screen Options expand it and remove the custom fields for the posts. True, I forgot the fact of the update permalinks... this was something that I used it in 3.5 / 3.7 change.

Answer (score -3):

you just need to create taxonomy-testcategory.php in your theme folder and reset your permalinks